# Extract the filepath from this ruby string

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, filenames

I am using the ruby Dir method to get all the filenames within a directory. Like this:

```
 dir_files = Dir["/Users/AM/Desktop/07/week1/dailies/regionals/*.csv"]
```

This gives me an array with each element listed below:

```
 /Users/AM/Desktop/07/week1/dailies/regionals/ch002.csv
 /Users/AM/Desktop/07/week1/dailies/regionals/ch014.csv
 /Users/AM/Desktop/07/week1/dailies/regionals/ch90.csv
 /Users/AM/Desktop/07/week1/dailies/regionals/ch112.csv
 /Users/AM/Desktop/07/week1/dailies/regionals/ch234.csv
```

Im trying to extract just the part of the above strings that matches: "regionals/*.csv"

How do I do that in Ruby?

The following didn't work

```
@files_array.each do |f|
     f = f.split("/").match(/*.csv/)
    i = f.include?(".csv")
    puts "#{i.inspect}"

    #self.process_file(f[i])
 end
```

Whats a clever way of doing this? I intend to pass the returned string of each filename to a helper method for processing. But as you can see all the csv files are located in a different directory as my executing script. 
My script thats executing this is located at

```
 /Users/AM/Desktop/07/week1/dailies/myScript.rb
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will always post back the final directory and file name, regardless of the file pattern:

```
@files_array.map { |f| f.split("/")[-2..-1].join("/") }
#=> ["regionals/ch002.csv", "regionals/ch014.csv", "regionals/ch90.csv", "regionals/ch112.csv", "regionals/ch234.csv"]
```

Comment: This solution is great because the word "regional" is not hard coded into the method. The directory name could be anything as long as the relative path of the script t the files doesnt change. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This gives you the desired values :)

```
dir_files.map {|path| path[/regionals\/.*.csv/]}
#=> ["regionals/ch002.csv", "regionals/ch014.csv", "regionals/ch90.csv", "regionals/ch112.csv", "regionals/ch234.csv"]
```

Comment: what is the output OP is looking for,I didn't get that. Could you help me out on that ? :(

Comment: Just added the output I think he is looking for ;)

Comment: Yeah! I just seen.. :)